# can't get the function transferred via props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have the component ExpenseForm

```js
class ExpenseForm extends Component {
 state = {
  description: '',
  amount: '',
  note: '',
  createdAt: moment(),
  calendarFocused: false,
  error: ''
 };

 onInputChange = (e) => {
  const prop = e.target.name;
  const val = e.target.value;

  if(prop === 'amount') {
   if(!val || val.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,2})?$/)) {
    this.setState(() => ({ [prop]:val }));
   }
  } else {
   this.setState(() => ({ [prop]:val }));
  }


 };

 onDateChange = (createdAt) => {
  if(createdAt) {
   this.setState(() => ({createdAt}));
  }
 };

 onFocusChange = ({focused}) => {
  this.setState(() => ({calendarFocused: focused}))
 };

 onFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const { description, amount, note, createdAt } = this.state;

  if(!description || !amount) {
   this.setState(() => ({error: 'Please provide description and amount'}));
  } else {
   this.setState(() => ({error: ''}));
          console.log(this.props.onSubmit) //<<< here i get undefined 
   this.props.onSubmit({
    description,
    amount: parseFloat(amount, 10) * 100,
    createdAt: createdAt.valueOf(),
    note
   });
  }
 };

 render() {
        console.log(this.props) //<<< here I see the object with the prop onSubmit, where lies the function onEditSubmit
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>Expense Form</h1>
    {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
     <input
      onChange={this.onInputChange}
      value={this.state.description}
      name="description"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Description"
      autoFocus
     />
     <input
      onChange={this.onInputChange}
      value={this.state.amount}
      name="amount"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Amount" />

     <SingleDatePicker
      date={this.state.createdAt}
       onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
       focused={this.state.calendarFocused}
       onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
       numberOfMonths={1}
      isOutsideRange={() => false }
     />

     <textarea
      onChange={this.onInputChange}
      value={this.state.note}
      name="note"
      placeholder="Add a note for your expense (optional)"
     ></textarea>

     <button>Add Expense</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

I use this component in two places
The first one is here

```js
function AddExpensePage({ addExpense, history }) {
 const onAddSubmit = (data) => {
  addExpense(data);
  history.push('/');
 };

 return (
  <div>
   <h1>AddExpensePage</h1>
   <ExpenseForm
    onSubmit={onAddSubmit}
   />
  </div>
 )
}
```

And the second one is here

```js
function EditPage(props) {
 const onEditSubmit = () => {
  console.log('edit submit')
 };

 return (
  <div>
   <h1>Edit Expense Page {props.match.params.id}</h1>
   <ExpenseForm
    onSumbit={onEditSubmit}
   />
  </div>
 )
}
```

In the first case everything works fine and I invoke the function transferred via props (onAddSubmit).

In the second one I get the error **_this.props.onSubmit is not a function**.
When I console.log the props of ExpenseForm I see in the object the function I transferred (onEditSubmit). But when I make console.log before calling this.props.onSubmit I see *undefined* in my console.
So I can't understand why this's happening.

Comment: onSumbit !== onSubmit. There is a typo in the ExpenseForm component of the  `EditPage`.

Comment: Oh, God! What a silly mistake. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :) This kind of error message is quite often a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is just a typo:

```
onSumbit={onEditSubmit}
```

Should be

```
onSubmit={onEditSubmit}
```